# Firebase Cloud Messaging: best practice

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm migrating to Firebase Cloud Messaging, and I have one doubt.
My application must show the login screen when launching, and if the user performs login in another account, I must stop send notifications for the older user.

- What's the best way to do that?
- Can I force the application to renew the token?
- Or should I update the token's owner in my base by my own?

Answer (score 4):

Inside application You should renew Instance ID token and forget about the old one if You don't want to get notifications being sent to the old token. On every logout and login just take new Instance ID and update Your external database (in case Your application logic need it) with information about new token being assigned to that user :) There are no limits for generating new tokens and You cannot reuse once dropped tokens.

Renewing token is just calling getToken() again.

This is the best approach because InstanceID is in fact assigned to the "application instance" so in case of app reinstall on device or removing cache by user You'll have to get new token anyway.

Comment: I've installed my app for the first time, and the function onTokenRefresh was called and gave me a new token. So, in some point I tried to call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(), and it's gave me the same token as before. Is it the method you said that regenerate the token number?

Answer (score 0):

In one of the apps I developed, I handled it on my app cloud.

Cloud had two tables, a table with device ids a user is logged in with and another with instance ids assigned to devices.

What you can do is, as user logs out from a device, remove that device id from users device list and as a new user log in you add a device id to his devices.

When sending notifications you can devices with tokens and everything else will streamlined